# Spring Security's redirect to login page returns 404

Tags: spring, spring-security, vaadin

I want to use [Spring Security 4.0.3](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) in my project but I don't really know how to do this in combination with the other technologies:

- [Vaadin 7.5.8](https://vaadin.com/home)
- [Vaadins official Spring Addon 1.0.0](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-spring)
- [Spring 4.2.1](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)
- [Tomcat 8 Server](http://tomcat.apache.org/)

I read a few articles about Vaadin and Spring Security but i didn't found anything about integreting it with the official Vaadin Spring Addon.

Because I'm new to Vaadin I followed [Vaadins official Spring tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Spring) and the [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html). I want to setup my project **without Spring Boot**! Currently I got the following:

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener
{
}

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class Servlet extends SpringVaadinServlet
{
}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // @formatter:off

         http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/VAADIN/**", "/UIDL/**", "/login**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/#!", true).permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();

        // @formatter:on

        // TODO plumb custom HTTP 403 and 404 pages
        /* http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access?error"); */
    }
}

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
}
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
[...]
<spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
[...]
<dependencies>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
[...]
```

Now I'm asking myself if I implemented it the right way. Preferably I don't want to use a web.xml instead I want to use Java configuration.

The server starts without an error but when I open the URL I get the following error message:

**HTTP Status 404 - Request was not handled by any registered handler.**

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

I don't know if I'm on the right way but I added an asterisk to "/*" in the annotation of the SpringVaadinServlet:
    @WebServlet(value = "/**", asyncSupported = true)

Now after the browser redirects to http://localhost:8080/myApp/login I get a normal 404 Not Found without anything...

Comment: I have a working integration of Vaadin and Spring Security available on GitHub. I'm aware that this approach does not quite answer your question, as I'm using Spring Boot (that's why I post a comment). Plus, I'm afraid there's not much documentation in place as yet. But maybe this example can push you in the right direction: https://github.com/rolandkrueger/vaadin-by-example/tree/master/en/architecture/SpringBootSecurity
Better than nothing, though ;-)

Comment: @RolandKrüger Thank you for your comment, although your GitHub project doesn't help me with my current problem (as you said). Nevertheless your project is a very nice reference for different Vaadin stuff :)

Comment: Glad you like it anyway ;-)